# C - what is wrong with my mergesort on linked list?

Tags: c, merge, printf, mergesort

I got to the point where my program compiles (through vim, if that matters), but returns garbage. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    int *val;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *addnode(int *val, struct node *next, int columns);
struct node *mergesort(struct node *head, int column);
struct node *merge(struct node *head_one, struct node *head_two, int column);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct node *head;
    struct node *current;
    struct node *next;
    int symbol = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    int rows = 0;
    head = NULL;
    int column = atoi(argv[1])-1;
    int lastSpace = 0;

    do {
        symbol = fgetc(stdin);

        if (rows == 0 && (lastSpace == 0 && (isspace(symbol) || feof(stdin)))) {
            columns++;
            lastSpace = 1;
        } else if (!isspace(symbol)) {
            lastSpace = 0;
        }
        if (symbol == '\n' || feof(stdin)) {
            rows++;
        };
    } while (symbol != EOF);

    if (ferror(stdin)) {
        printf("Error on reading from file.\n");
    } else {
        printf("The file contains %d row(s) and %d column(s).\n", rows, columns);
    };

    rewind(stdin); //ignore it - it works in this case

    int table[rows][columns], i, j;
    puts("Original file:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        head = addnode(*table, head, columns);
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&table[i][j]);
            head->val[j] = table[i][j];
            printf("%d ",head->val[j]);
        };
        puts("\n");
    };

    /* Up to this point everything works */
    head = mergesort(head, column);

    printf("Sorted by %d column:\n", column+1);
    for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            printf("%d ", current->val[j]); //suspect number 1 - printing loop prints only last node, instead node-by-node
        };//I removed a }; in this area
        puts("\n");
    };

    for(current = head; current != NULL; current = next)
        next = current->next, free(current);
    return 0;
};


struct node *addnode(int *val, struct node *next, int columns)
{
    struct node *tnode;
    tnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*tnode));
    if(tnode != NULL) {
        tnode->val = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns); //suspect number 2 - I'm not sure I allocated memory correctly, it should allocate array of integers
        memcpy(tnode->val, val, sizeof(int) * columns);
        tnode->val = val;
        tnode->next = next;
    };
    return tnode;
}

struct node *mergesort(struct node *head, int column) //suspect number 3 - my modified mergesort duplicates last node
{
    struct node *head_one;
    struct node *head_two;
    if((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
        return head;
    head_one = head;
    head_two = head->next;
    while((head_two != NULL) && (head_two->next != NULL)) {
        head = head->next;
        head_two = head->next->next;
    };
    head_two = head->next;
    head->next = NULL;
    return merge(mergesort(head_one, column), mergesort(head_two, column), column);
}

struct node *merge(struct node *head_one, struct node *head_two, int column) //suspect number 4 - instead of merging, it duplicates nodes
{
    struct node *head_combined;
    if(head_one == NULL)
        return head_two;
    if(head_two == NULL)
        return head_one;
    if(head_one->val[column] < head_two->val[column]) {
        head_combined = head_one;
        head_combined->next = merge(head_one->next, head_two, column);
    } else {
        head_combined = head_two;
        head_combined->next = merge(head_one, head_two->next, column);
    };
    return head_combined;
}
```

I run it from a command line like so:
    name_of_program column < test.txt

test.txt looks like this

```
1   4  100  34   12
12  2  45   6     7
5   8   1   87  101
5   4  10   12   33
```

And instead of list sorted by `column` column, I get array from last node from test.txt 4 times. I have no idea how to analyse it step-by-step in vim, and I think that would help me pinpoint the problem.

Comment: If you want to analyze step by step, if you're using VIM I assume you have GDB on your system.  Look into that.  http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/  Or you could try developing in an IDE like Eclipse, XCode, or Visual Studio.

Comment: TL;DR. Try narrowing down your problem to something smaller.

Comment: vim is not a debugger.  You need to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @H2CO3 I pointed places I'm suspicious of, and pasted whole code, because another user told me that not doing that makes it hard to give advice.

Comment: Can you provide an input file?

Comment: @ChrisCM It's at the end of my post. Simple .txt file with 2D array of integers.

Comment: Oh,my mistake, I thought you were saying that was your output and you had reversed the >.  Gotcha.

Comment: @ChrisCM No, that's my mistake, I should include output too. It's just the last array `5 4 10 12 33` 4 times, one under another.

Comment: I believe there's a typo in your code.  I'm proposing an edit, check it for me so I know it's what you want, and accept it in case others are looking into this.  You had an extra }; in there, I removed it.

Comment: @ChrisCM It made code clearer, but the sorting is still borked.

Comment: With the extra }; it wasn't compiling... I wanted to make sure it was errant, and there wasn't something missing!

Comment: @ChrisCM It compiled for me either way, but that was much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you're passing `table` into `addNode`. The way you're calling it, the row you want to put into the node you're adding hasn't been read from the file yet.

These two lines need to go, but what did you intend with the second line ?
By that point, you've already allocated space for `tnode->val` and copied data from `val` to it.

```
memcpy(tnode->val, val, sizeof(int) * columns);
tnode->val = val;   /// What's this for ???
```

I think this

```
head_two = head->next->next;
```

should be

```
head_two = head_two->next->next;
```

It seems like you're trying to find the midpoint here, so `head_two` needs to walk twice as fast as `head`.

Comment: Holy hell, it works! Thank you so much. Now I have to just add some error handling, but the most important thing is that it sorts things. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to pay attention to the details. It might be a worthwhile exercise to thoroughly comment your code. You might pick up on some other bugs too.